# How do I use Transform.RotateAround to gradually rotate my GameObject around a new pivot in the shortest direction?

Tags: unity, rotation, quaternion

Given a normalized `Vector2` or `eulerAngles.z`, I'm trying to gradually rotate a 2D box around a new pivot (the top of the box) using `Transform.RotateAround`. My issue is that I don't know how to stop rotating once the desired rotation has been reached, nor do I understand how to figure out the direction of rotation so that the box rotates the shortest amount.

Right now my box seems to overshoot the rotation most of the time, often rotating forever; and the rotation "direction" is inconsistent, sometimes rotating the box "backwards," nearly 360 degrees, to reach the given rotation value.

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider2D))]
public class RotationTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float targetRotationZ = 45f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float rotationSpeed = 200f;

    private BoxCollider2D boxCollider;

    private void Awake()
    {
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Rotate();
    }

    private void Rotate()
    {
        // The rotation pivot is now the top of the box
        Vector2 newPivot = transform.position + transform.up * boxCollider.bounds.extents.y;

        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, targetRotationZ));

        if (transform.rotation == targetRotation)
            return;

        transform.RotateAround(newPivot, Vector3.forward, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

To be more specific about my ultimate use case: I want to rotate my character around a new pivot based on the averaged normals of the ground below it, which I gather from several raycasts. Before attempting to use `Transform.RotateAround`, I was rotating around the default pivot, like this:

```
Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, someNormal);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

How can I adapt `Transform.RotateAround` to achieve results similar to this? Perhaps there's also a more appropriate way to do this about which I'm not aware.

By the way, I did write a custom function that I believe does what I want, but would still like to know how to achieve this with `Transform.RotateAround` since it does seem like Unity intended that function to be used in a situation like this.

```
public void Rotate(Vector2 pivotPoint, Quaternion targetRotation)
{
    Vector2 offset = transform.InverseTransformPoint(pivotPoint);

    transform.rotation = targetRotation;

    Vector2 localPivotToWorld = transform.TransformPoint(offset);
    transform.Translate(pivotPoint - localPivotToWorld, Space.World);
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a situation where I would use [`Quaternion.RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html). But that method does not allow to set a pivot.